# Hangouts: Cannot Connect to Server After Update

Tags: google-hangouts

Recently, Google released a fairly major update to Hangouts, an instant messaging app as well as an alternate SMS client. I have a phone (model is irrelevant) and a Nexus 10. I updated to the latest hangouts on both devices.

On the phone, it works great. On my Nexus 10 however I get a 'Cannot Connect to Server' Error when starting the app:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: Screenshot of error]

It is odd because if I click on a notification of a message it will go straight to the conversation and not cause any issues. The main issue seems to happen when signing in to the main page:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: signing in]

<sub>To be clear, I still get notifications about messages, but I cannot open them in the app:</sub> [image: Hangouts Notification]

My Nexus 10 is running android 5.0.2 on the RemixOS ROM. I have tried going to stock android 5.1.1, wiping cache, user data and dalvik cache all to no avail.
**Does anyone have a fix to this problem? If not, are there any good Google Voice clients?**

Answer (score 0):

I have had an issue like this with a past update on Hangouts and fixed it by updating my "Google Play Services".
Other things I tried that may have inadvertently helped was restarting and connected to WiFi.

Comment: I'll check if play services is updated, however I have I installed 3 new ROMs and it still is not fixed.

Comment: wow 3 ROMs, I would guess then that the play services is not the issue. Sorry I was not able to help.

Comment: Thanks for the help though..maybe someone else will find the answer useful :) (And yes, I have yet to find my perfect ROM haha)